# Routing based on path in Dokku

Tags: nginx, docker, dokku

I'm trying to develop some kind of a service-based architecture using Dokku. But by default Dokku routes based on a subdomain. What I need to do is like this :
api.example.com/service1/
api.example.com/service2/

Where service1 is it's own container and service2 is in another container.

Any suggestions ?

BTW, I've tried this plugin https://github.com/fkowal/dokku-path-proxy. It didn't work

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up doing is that I've forked this plugin https://github.com/fkowal/dokku-path-proxy to support the latest version of Dokku and it's now working fine.
The fork can be found here https://github.com/hussam-almarzoq/dokku-path-proxy